# How can I target the nearest input[type] when I click the i tag in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am working on this update form. The idea is that initially, the `inputs` are not editable until the icons near them are clicked. Since most of them have the same classes I figured that I should work mostly in the classes part of the form however I am still really stuck here.

However, so far no luck. I hope someone could tell me the workaround for this one.

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="../php/">
        <div class="parent">
          <div class="kid1">
            <label>Name</label>
          </div>
          <div class="kid2">
            <input class="input_inner no_border" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" value ="<?php  echo $name ?>" required readonly>
            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="parent">
          <div class="kid1">
            <label>Civ Status</label>
          </div>
          <div class="kid2">
            <select name="civil_status" id="cv_stat" class="no_border" required readonly>
              <option value="<?php echo $cv ?>"><?php echo $cv ?></option>
              <option value="Single">Single</option>
              <option value="Married">Married</option>
              <option value="Widowed">Widowed</option>
              <option value="Separated">Anulled</option>
            </select>
            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="parent">
          <div class="kid1">
            <label>Email</label>
          </div>
          <div class="kid2">
            <input type="email" name="email" class="no_border" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo $email ?>"required readonly>
            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="parent">
          <div class="kid1">
            <label>Address</label>
          </div>
          <div class="kid2">
            <input type="text" name="address" class="no_border" placeholder="Address" value="<?php echo $address ?>"required readonly>
            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="parent">
          <div class="kid1">
            <label>Contact</label>
          </div>
          <div class="kid2">
            <input type="number" name="contact" class="no_border" placeholder="Contact" value="<?php echo $contact ?>"required readonly>
            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="parent">
        <div class="kid1">
          <label>Gender</label>
        </div>
        <div class="kid1">
          <select name="gender" class="no_border" id="gender" required readonly>
            <option value="<?php echo $gnder ?>"><?php echo $gnder ?></option>
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
            <option value="Gay">Gay</option>
            <option value="Lesbian">Lesbian</option>
            <option value="Trans">Trans</option>
            <option value="Pan">Pan</option>
          </select>
          <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
        </div>
        </div>
        <h4>Dependents</h4>
        <div>
          <input type="text" name="d1" placeholder="Dependent 1" class="no_border" value="<?php echo $d1 ?>" readonly>
          <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" name="d2" placeholder="Dependent 2" class="no_border" value="<?php echo $d2 ?>" readonly>
          <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" name="d3" placeholder="Dependent 3" class="no_border" value="<?php echo $d3 ?>" readonly>
          <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" name="d4" placeholder="Dependent 4" class="no_border" value="<?php echo $d4 ?>" readonly>
          <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" name="submit">
  </form>
```

Jquery -  Here I thought that the `closest()` object could fix however it might be a case that I am misinterpreting the real function of the object. I really hope someone could help me with this one. Thank you

```
$(".fa-pencil").click(function(){
    $(".fa-pencil").not($(this)).closest("input").attr("readonly", true);
    const elem = $(this).closest(".input_inner");
    alert(elem.val())
    elem.css("background", "red");
    if(elem.attr("readonly", true)) elem.attr("readonly", false);
    else elem.attr("readonly", false);
});
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: If in doubt, review the/some documentation [jquery closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [javascript closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) - but get the "closest parent"

Comment: You *probably* want `$(".fa-pencil").prev()` given your layout

Comment: Are you in control of the code/markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`closest()` searches for parent elements only. The `input` or `select` you're attempting to find is a previous sibling.

The easiest, most reliable and most extensible way to address this is to use `closest()` to find a common parent of both the `i` which raised the event and the target form control, then `find()` to get the `input` directly. However as your HTML structure changes lower in the form, either the `prev()` or `siblings()` methods can be used here.

Note that I expanded the logic slightly so that the 'edit' `i` element can be used as a toggle to return the control to a readonly state when editing is completed.

In addition you should note that best practice is to use `prop()` over `attr()` where possible, and also to use CSS classes instead of inline styling.

With that said, try this:

```js
$(".fa-pencil").click(function() {
  $(".fa-pencil").not(this).prev('input').prop("readonly", true).removeClass('active');
  
  $(this).prev('input, select')
    .toggleClass('active')
    .prop('readonly', (i, r) => !r);
});
```

```css
.active { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="../php/">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="kid1">
      <label>Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="kid2">
      <input class="input_inner no_border" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="<?php  echo $name ?>" required readonly>
      <i class="fa fa-pencil">Edit</i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="kid1">
      <label>Civ Status</label>
    </div>
    <div class="kid2">
      <select name="civil_status" id="cv_stat" class="no_border" required readonly>
        <option value="<?php echo $cv ?>">
          <?php echo $cv ?>
        </option>
        <option value="Single">Single</option>
        <option value="Married">Married</option>
        <option value="Widowed">Widowed</option>
        <option value="Separated">Anulled</option>
      </select>
      <i class="fa fa-pencil">Edit</i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="kid1">
      <label>Email</label>
    </div>
    <div class="kid2">
      <input type="email" name="email" class="no_border" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo $email ?>" required readonly>
      <i class="fa fa-pencil">Edit</i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="kid1">
      <label>Address</label>
    </div>
    <div class="kid2">
      <input type="text" name="address" class="no_border" placeholder="Address" value="<?php echo $address ?>" required readonly>
      <i class="fa fa-pencil">Edit</i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="kid1">
      <label>Contact</label>
    </div>
    <div class="kid2">
      <input type="number" name="contact" class="no_border" placeholder="Contact" value="<?php echo $contact ?>" required readonly>
      <i class="fa fa-pencil">Edit</i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="kid1">
      <label>Gender</label>
    </div>
    <div class="kid1">
      <select name="gender" class="no_border" id="gender" required readonly>
        <option value="<?php echo $gnder ?>">
          <?php echo $gnder ?>
        </option>
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
        <option value="Gay">Gay</option>
        <option value="Lesbian">Lesbian</option>
        <option value="Trans">Trans</option>
        <option value="Pan">Pan</option>
      </select>
      <i class="fa fa-pencil">Edit</i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h4>Dependents</h4>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="d1" placeholder="Dependent 1" class="no_border" value="<?php echo $d1 ?>" readonly>
    <i class="fa fa-pencil">Edit</i>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="d2" placeholder="Dependent 2" class="no_border" value="<?php echo $d2 ?>" readonly>
    <i class="fa fa-pencil">Edit</i>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="d3" placeholder="Dependent 3" class="no_border" value="<?php echo $d3 ?>" readonly>
    <i class="fa fa-pencil">Edit</i>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="d4" placeholder="Dependent 4" class="no_border" value="<?php echo $d4 ?>" readonly>
    <i class="fa fa-pencil">Edit</i>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```